# High Fixed Cost and Zero VC

Tags: monopoly, profit-maximization

Suppose a Monopoly has a High **Fixed Cost= **0.5**** and **VC=**0**** . 
The Profit Max O/t : **Q=1**
But the **Profit = **-0.13**** (which is < 0)

which means -0.13 > -0.5

Should the Firm Produce produce **Q=1 or Q=0** ?

---

**Soln.**

I am confused here. The answer says Q=0  ,but doesn't it make sense to produce 1 Q and sell it and offset it to the fixed cost.But if it produces Q=0 it will still have a sunk cost of -0.5.

There is no mention of LR & SR in the question ,so I suppose its talking about LR .

Comment: Could you please post the question exactly as it was originally posed?  Your version is not very clear.